# IBM Graph query result to Graph representation

Tags: ibm-graph

Is there any way that we can plot the query result from IBM Graph DB to a graph representation?

Answer (score 1):

IBM graph has UI for basic plotting of nodes and edges. feel free to reach out to us on our public slack for help there: http://ibm-graph-slackinvite.mybluemix.net/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I basically wanted to know if there's an external utility that I can use to show the result graphically on my website as IBM UI does.

Answer (score 0):

this may be helpful: https://cambridge-intelligence.com/keylines/ibm-graph/

there are also multiple graphing utilities you can implement, but you have to do the work of mapping the graph..etc (ex: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) you choice would also depend on how much you are trying to display and what you are trying to do (ex: zooming, clustering, filtering, calculations to best show the graph...etc). feel free to come to the public slack channel i mentioned and we can help ya with our experience.